# String not recogized as valid DateTime - from web page

Tags: c#, datetime

Attempting to add a date validation to a .NET webpage (using C#). Comparing start date with end date to make sure that end date > start date.

For some reason, I'm getting the following error:

> String was not recognized as valid a DateTime.

Now I admit that this is my first go around with the DateTime method, so I may not completely understand it yet, but as near as I can tell, my code should be good.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

```
String startD = Request["txtStartDate"]; //requesting string from textbox "txtStartDate"
String endD = Request["txtEndDate"];
DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(startD); //line that throws the error
DateTime end = DateTime.Parse(endD);
```

Comment: Can we see that Request["txtStartDate"] is returning?

Comment: Please show us contents of `Request["txtStartDate"]` and `Request["txtEndDate"]`. You can get them by debugging or Console outputting or any other way that you can.

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen Yes I agree. We can't do anything unless we see the input

Comment: The value entered by the user in txtStartDate is not a valid input for DateTime datatype. See the Standard Date and Time Format Strings [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Assuming that I understand your question correctly, the txtStartDate / txtEndDate requests simply returns text strings in format MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: Well, if you know the expected input format, the first thing I'd try is ParseExact *telling* it to expect MM/dd/yyyy - but it would be good to see an actual sample input value

Comment: What did you not understand about the exception message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is coming because the input you are giving is in `MM/dd/yyyy`. The .net may consider the format as `dd/MM/yyy`. So if your input is `02/13/2015` it may fail because there is no month beyond 12. So try `ParseExact`

try below

```
String startD = Request["txtStartDate"]; 
String endD = Request["txtEndDate"];
DateTime start = DateTime.ParseExact(startD, "MM/dd/yyyy",
                  new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None);
DateTime end = DateTime.ParseExact(endD, "MM/dd/yyyy",
                  new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None);
```

OR

```
 String startD = Request["txtStartDate"]; 
 String endD = Request["txtEndDate"];
 DateTime start = DateTime.ParseExact(startD,"MM/dd/yyyy",
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    DateTime end = DateTime.ParseExact(endD,"MM/dd/yyyy",
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For more info [Msdn Doc for ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Sachu, but it still throws the same error. I think I'm looking at this wrong. I think sohaiby is right in his comment above and its the formatting of my textbox input that's the problem. I'm gonna have to go back and research this a little more. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @tworley1977 when u debug whats the value assigning to startD and endD? if it is MM/dd/yyyy the above code will definetly work in C#

Comment: Just wanted to touch base and let you guys know that I found the issue. It wasn't with my DateTime code at all; both my original DateTime code as well as the code provided by Sachu work just fine. The problem ended up being that I wasn't placing the value from my textbox into the variables. It was a simple typo in my code that I kept overlooking.